# Replace part of strings by the corresponding code R

Tags: r, string

In a large dataset, I need to replace the territory names by their corresponding code.

Here below a small replicable example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringi)

adrs_data <- data.frame (adress  = c("6 Frien Street, Paris", "Toulouse, 7 Hospital street", "10 market avenue (Bordeaux)") )

dep_code <- data.frame (code  = c("75", "31", "33"), names  = c("Paris", "Toulouse", "Bordeaux"))
```

This is what I have tried:

```r
d_search<-c(dep_code$names)
d_search <- paste(paste0(d_search[order(-nchar(d_search))]), collapse = "|")
c_search<-c(dep_code $code)

df<-adrs_data %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(c_adress = case_when(adress %in% d_search ~ 
            str_replace_all(adress,  d_search, c_search), TRUE ~ adress))
```

But it does not produce the wanted output which is:

```r
df <- data.frame (adress  = c("6 Frien Street, 75", "31, 7 Hospital street", "10 market avenue (33)")
```

Thank you for your help,
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After merging both data frames, you can use `pmap` to replace the pattern for each row:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_left_join(adrs_data, dep_code, match_fun = str_detect, 
                by = c("adress" = "names")) %>% 
  mutate(adress = pmap(., ~ str_replace(..1, ..3, ..2)))

#                  adress code    names
# 1    6 Frien Street, 75   75    Paris
# 2 31, 7 Hospital street   31 Toulouse
# 3 10 market avenue (33)   33 Bordeaux
```

Comment: it is not clear to me that the data frames are of the same lenghts. i *assume* that the `adrs_data` has many times the length (while not necessarily being a multiple)  of `dep_code`. so merging them might not be a straight forward process. still a great idea!

Comment: Doing a merge does exactly that, it works irrespective of both data frames number of rows

Answer (score 0):

This also works and removes parenthesis:

I added one more entry to `adrs_data`

```
adrs_data <- data.frame (adress  = c("6 Frien Street, Paris", "Toulouse, 7 Hospital street", "10 market avenue (Bordeaux)", "9 Test Street, Paris") )

dep_code <- data.frame (code  = c("75", "31", "33"), names  = c("Paris", "Toulouse", "Bordeaux")) 

sapply(seq(nrow(adrs_data)), \(i){ 
  adrs_data[i,] %>% 
    str_replace_all(dep_code$names, dep_code$code) %>% 
    .[.!= adrs_data[i,]] %>% 
    sub(pattern = "\\(", replacement = "", x = .) %>% 
    sub(pattern = "\\)", replacement = "", x = .) 
})

     [,1]                   
[1,] "6 Frien Street, 75"   
[2,] "31, 7 Hospital street"
[3,] "10 market avenue 33"  
[4,] "9 Test Street, 75"
```

For very short data this even provides decent speed.

```
Unit: milliseconds
       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
  1.508001  1.671950  2.481109  1.823151  2.534501  11.9309   100 # lapply
 58.665500 67.577851 85.267257 76.948251 89.716950 231.3375   100 # fuzzy
```

Would be interesting to compare with @Maël's solution for a big data set.
I assume the larger the data the slower the lapply solution.